# Emulating linerenderer in unity 3d going wrong horribly(has different start height and end height)

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So trying to draw a path for player to move, this path is denoted by linerenderer. Line is drawn based on mousepositions. But putting the camera in top down view is messing up linerenderer , making it invisible. The problem is mouseposition is having varying heights. How do i have mouse position to not have varying heights, say it has to have a constant y axis value.

This is the code. Liner is the linerenderer

if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) // mouse
        {

```
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hitinfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitinfo))
        {
            if (Dist(hitinfo.point) > 1f)
            {

                points.Add(hitinfo.point);
                liner.positionCount = points.Count;
                liner.SetPositions(points.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

Then i have another script , moving the character on this mouse path. unfortunetly what happens is that, the start position of the line is having a different height than end position. so how to emulate line drawn on mouseposition but having same height(to get a 2d screen effect) ?

Comment: Make sure your LineRenderer's Alignment option is set to "View". Also, set `var point = hitinfo.point; point.z= 0;` and add that `point` to `points`.

Comment: this solved the problem, thank you.